# CNN model validation accuracy is not improving

Tags: python, keras

I am currently working on a CNN model for classification, I have to predict words on a wav file. I encountered a problem with my validation accuracy that stays (almost) the same, first I was thinking of overfitting but that does not seem to be the problem. Below you can see a photo with the result at the different epochs:[image]

I am building a CNN model with Keras and using the 'adam' optimizer and 'categorical_crossentropy' for the loss. I already have tried to increase the number of epochs until 1000 and changed the batch size.

Comment: Please paste loss/val plots from tensorboard.

Comment: dId you split the data you have into training/validation sets or is the validation data from another source?

Comment: We had one training set which we splitted into training and validation set and we have a different test set. The training set is with labels and the test set is without labels which we have to predict correct. The following code is used:
`trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(audio_features3,final_labels1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
train = trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0], 99, 13, 1)`
 And

`CNN=model.fit(train,trainY, batch_size=100, epochs=8)
CNN=model.fit(train,trainY, validation_split = 0.1, batch_size=100, epochs=20)
`

Answer (score 0):

Your training loss seems to be decreasing but val_loss is increasing while val_accuracy is approximately same. This is standard case of overfitting. Why do you think that's not the case?

---

Increasing the training epochs or batch size is not helpful as you're just changing the number of times the model sees the data or the quantity of data it sees in one epoch.

---

For current scenario, the best model is created till the point both val_loss and train_loss continues to decrease before it becomes saturated.
To address the problem, you need to add noise in the training data so that the model generalizes better, generalize the examples better, create balanced categories in terms of training data volume.

---

Secondly, you can increase your validation dataset to see if it continues to have the same issue. If it's there then the model is definitely overfitting. ALso please update your question about what kind of validation set and technique you're using. If possible, add the code snippet of your validation set and loss function

Comment: Thank you all! You convinced me in that the model is overfitting. I've posted my code, is the only option to add noise in my training data or are there other methods to avoid this model from overfitting?

Comment: These are some of the steps to avoid overfitting:
1. Add more data
2. Use data augmentation
3. Use architectures that generalize well
4. Add regularization (mostly dropout, L1/L2 regularization are also possible)
5. Reduce architecture complexity.
For more detail It'd be helpful if you read a detailed article or blog post on this like :https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-3-more-on-cnns-handling-overfitting-2bd5d99abe5d